# WideVine in chromium-beta ppa not working

Tags: chrome, ppa

After Updating to Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon (From 19.3) I have found that Chromium is a dummy package and Chromium is no longer available as an apt. I added the chromium-beta ppa ([https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta](https://launchpad.net/%7Esaiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta)) and saw that WideVine was enabled (yay!) I got the package and downloaded the Chrome 64-bit deb and extracted the contents. Then I copied `libwidevinecdm.so` to `~/.config/chromium` (Which was where it had said to put it.) and restarted Chromium. I went to Netflix to see if it had worked but it hadn't! I tried logging out and back in, then restarting but it didn't work! Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or if I am even doing anything wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Anyone having the same issue follow these instructions.

1. Download Google Chrome
2. Use `dpkg -x google-chrome.deb` to extract it
3. cd to `opt/google/chrome/` within the extracted deb
4. Move `WidevineCdm` to /usr/lib/chromium-browser
5. Edit `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`
6. After every time it says `Exec: chromium-browser (args here)`, write

```
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
```

This will make Netflix (and other Widevine-Using Streaming Services) think you are using Chrome which supports WideVine, instead of Chromium, which doesn't. Also, pages that will tell you which browser you are using will say 'Chrome' From Now On. Ignore It.

7. Restart Chromium.